# iCloud key value pair entitlement issues

Tags: icloud, entitlements

When I tried uploading it I got the following errors

Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, key 'com.apple.developer.icloud-containter-identifiers' in 'Payload/Appname.app/Appname' is not supported

Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, key 'com.apple.developer.icloud-containter-development-identifiers' in 'Payload/Appname.app/Appname' is not supported

Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, key 'com.apple.developer.icloud-services' in 'Payload/Appname.app/Appname' is not supported

Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, key 'com.apple.developer.icloud-containter-environment' in 'Payload/Appname.app/Appname' is not supported

PLEASE PLEASE help. I have tried redoing the provisioning profiles and I am using key-value pair for iCloud. Seemingly simple stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the solution for this (I am using Xcode 5.1.1).

I have uploaded a new version (1.1) of my existing app in which I have introduced an iCloud feature, which was not present on the previous version.

While uploading the build it showed the same error as yours (as seen in your question).

The solution is:

1- Open apple developer account.
2- Edit your AppID
3- Uncheck the iCloud container which you selected before.(While uncheck, iCloud will show configurable and leave it as "Configurable").
4- Edit your provision profile and download it again.

Open the provision profile and submit the build to the App Store.

Hope this works for you too.

Comment: While giving support for iCloud, Should we enable iCloud in existing working app ID or should we create new app ID with iCloud enabled?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same bug/issue today. The fix almost worked, but interestingly when I set it back to "configurable", it added a *maps reference in my .info file! This of course created an error on a new Validate, which was unfathomable to me as my app DOES NOT use maps! I deleted the strangely added "maps" reference that was "created magically" by "unchecking" the iCloud container, and then the Validation went fine. Thanks!